# Hydra too slow - Counter BruteForce protection?

Tags: hydra

I'm trying to bruteforce with Hydra (I'm a newbie).

But it takes too much time, only 15 attempts in 30 minutes for example...
I tried to inform myself about this problem, and it seems to be slow because of a Bruteforce protection on some websites.

Am I wrong?

If not, what is the way to skirt this problem?

Here's my request :

```
hydra -L /root/Desktop/login.txt -P /root/Desktop/password1.txt 91.XXX.XXX.XX https-post-form "/blog/?connect=1:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Attention : Ton pseudo ou ton mot de passe sont incorrects !"
```

Comment: Do you have a PtA for this website you are attacking?

Comment: What is a PtA? I don't know what you mean

Comment: "PtA" means "Permission to Attack", meaning permission from the system owner that you are allowed to attack them.

Comment: Okey, thank you. Yes, of course, these tries are made on my own website, or i'm using localhost, or dvwa.

Comment: You are attempting to explain to me that you have "some sort brute force protection", which you don't know about, on your own webserver? Sorry, but I am not buying that.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. I thought that doing this in my own website (hosted on OVH) was not a problem, but you mean that the fact that it is not my own webserver is a problem?

Comment: You are correct. You may own the website, but not the hardware hosting it, or the infrastructure surrounding it. If you wish to attack your website, then you need explicit written permission from the infrastructure owner, otherwise you can and will get into legal trouble.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information, I will take precautions from now. But how this question can be off-topic? If we imagine ourselves as a White Hat Hacker, we have to imagine that our security can be broken

Comment: Read the message in the info box, as to why it is considered off-topic: `"Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem."` These questions are specifically marked as off-topic, as otherwise hundreds of questions regarding specific systems would pop up, which would be of no use to anyone else, except the person originally asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read the doc. 
If there's some way to speed up this on hydra side, it will be written on the doc.
For example, by reading the doc, i noticed the `-t TASKS` argument that allows you to specify how many tasks must be run simultaneously.

Then, monitor what is happening: launch a `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see what side of the exchange is taking too much time.

Comment: I'm going to check this. But my question is still the same, how to counter a BruteForce protection?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: depends on how is implemented the brute force protection. If it's IP based, you must come with a different IP address for each attempts... there's some way to do this, but you must try to learn by yourself. If protection consists in allowing only X authentication attemps  per minutes, regardless of source IP, then you just can't do anything but wait.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your idea of coming with a different IP address for each attempt is very interesting. Can you guide me on this? I think about a VPN which would change IP each second, or something like this

Comment: Have a look to Tor. If i remember well, it allows changing circuit for each new connections